# Как подружить selenium и прокси?

Tags: python, http, proxy, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Написал парсинг прокси из файла и отправку нужных мне данных на странице. Как теперь сделать запуск вебдрайвера через прокси?

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
phantomjs_path = r'/var/www/goodwin/hulk/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs'

def proxyread():
    try:
        with open(path+'/proxy-rus.txt', 'rb') as proxyfile:
            proxylist = proxyfile.read().split('\n')
    except Exception:
        with open(path+'/proxy-rus.txt', 'wb') as proxyfile:
            n.write()
        proxylist = False
    return proxylist

def poster():
    comm = unicode(' ', 'utf8')
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path, service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
    browser.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    browser.get("https://example.com")
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.find_element_by_id(r"reply").click()
    browser.implicitly_wait(0.1)
    browser.find_element_by_name(r"comment").send_keys(comm)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(r'input[id=subject]').send_keys(comm)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(r'input[id=name]').send_keys(comm)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(r'input[type=file]').send_keys(r'1.jpg')
    browser.find_element_by_name(r"submit").click()

poster()
```

Answer (score 1):

Краткий ответ - selenium скорее всего использует системный proxy. В разных операционных системах он задается по-разному, Ваш К.О.

Более подробно в справке selenium: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Для PhantomJS используйте следующие вариант кода:

```
service_args = [

    '--proxy=127.0.0.1:9999',
    '--proxy-type=socks5',
    ]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('../path_to/phantomjs',service_args=service_args)
```